# Itrying to find the path of a node in a binary tree by a vector function but I am getting only 2 values from the starting node in output of the vector

Tags: c++17, binary-tree

I am trying to find the path of a node in a binary tree by a
vector function but I am getting only 2 values from the of
starting of the node in output of the vector
like I am trying to find the path of the node 10 and my output
would be in the following way---(1 3 7 9 10),but I am getting
only (1 3) in the output

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;

    node(int val)
    {
        data = val;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};
vector<int> path(node *root, int x)
{
    static vector<int> v;
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return v;
    }
    v.push_back(root->data);
    if (root->data == x)
    {
        v.push_back(x);
        return v;
    }
    path(root->left, x);
    path(root->right, x);
    v.pop_back();
    return v;
}
int main()
{
    struct node *root = new node(1);
    root->left = new node(2);
    root->right = new node(3);
    root->left->left = new node(4);
    root->left->right = new node(5);
    root->left->right->left = new node(11);
    root->right->left = new node(6);
    root->right->right = new node(7);
    root->right->right->right = new node(9);
    root->right->right->right->right = new node(10);

    int x = 10;
    vector<int> v = path(root, x);
    cout << v.size();
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << "  ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The algorithm in `path` doesn't make much sense to me. Off the top, `path(root, root->data)` returns a vector of two elements, with `root->data` repeated twice.

Comment: A simpler repro: if you have a tree that's really a linked list, all branches in one direction: `struct node *root = new node(1); root->left = new node(2); root->left->left = new node(3); ...` No matter how long the list, the result is always `(1, 2)`. There are exactly two more pushes than pops.